# viewWillAppear not invoked when presenting the viewController modally (iOS)

Tags: iphone

I have an issue, viewWillAppear method in the UIViewController which is added to the screen by presentModalViewController method does not "go into" viewWillAppear method. Only time this method is invoked is together with the viewDidLoad, the first time.

```
- (IBAction)openModal:(id)sender {  
if (self.nvc == nil) {
    ModalViewController *vc = [[ModalViewController alloc] init];
    self.nvc = vc;
    [vc release];
}
self.nvc.segmentedIndex = [[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] index];
[self presentModalViewController:self.nvc animated:YES];
}
```

The property is of type *retain.*

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

right, it works different and it now goes into viewWillAppear only once. So if you want to change the appearance of your view after dismissing a modal view you should do it using a modal delegate pattern. See the link:

http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/5/3/ipad-modal-view-controllers.html

Though it's for iPad, but you can get the idea. In the latest iOS versions it works the same.

Hope it helps